# C++ multithreading - beginner query

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm learning about multithreading in C++. I'm following a tutorial that gave this example for explaining the way to 'move' from one thread to another using the move semantics:

```
std::thread thread_1( func_1 );
std::thread thread_2 = std::move( thread_1 ); 

thread_1 = std::thread(func_2); 
std::thread thread_3 = std::move(thread_2);

thread_1 = std::move(thread_3);
```

The last line `thread_1 = std::move(thread_3);` was indicated as not being a proper way of doing it because(as I understood it):

'thread_1' and 'thread_3' are both existing threads which own some functions(thread_1 owns func_2 and thread_3 owns func_1) and you are supposed to manage their life-cycle with .detach() or .join();

That was the explanation given in the tutorial however that doesn't make sense to me 100%. Please help me better understand that explanation of why that line of code is not a proper way to transfer ownership between threads. Thank you!

Comment: Are you allowed to share the link to the tutorial. Some more context may help people answer your question.

Comment: Start with the [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) reference, or even better with a good [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the point is you can not *move* a running thread onto a thread object that is already running a thread. If you do, the program will end by calling `std::trerminate`.

See the reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D).

You can only move a running thread onto a thread object that has been default constructed (without a function) or that has previously been moved *from*, or has been joined/detached (leaving it empty).

Comment: @MikeMB thnx for the input

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the right side of the assignment (`thread_3`) is irrelevant. You must not assign **to** an `std::thread` object that is joinable (is a handle to an OS thread), otherwise `std::terminate` is called:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not show much awareness of the difference between a `std::thread` *variable*, a `std::thread` *value*, and a *thread*.  Those are three different things.  Your three initialization and assignment statements *move* (or, attempting to move) `std::thread` values from variable to variable.

When you *move* a `std::thread` value, you actually are calling a function:  This is a function call:

```
thread_1 = std::move(thread_3);
```

It's calling a `std::thread` member function named

```
std::thread::operator= (std::thread&& other)
```

And, it does three things.  It must first *destroy* (i.e., effectively call the destructor of) the value of `thread_1`, then it copies the guts of the `thread_3` value into `thread_1`, and then finally it must effectively "zero out" the `thread_3` variable.

That fails in the first step--destroying the old `thread_1` value--because the *thread* already is running.

The *thread* is not the variable, and it is not the value of the variable.  The *thread* is an object in the operating system kernel, and the value of the `thread_1` variable is merely a *handle* to the operating system object.

One of the rules enforced by the `std::thread` class is that it won't allow you to destroy the *handle* to a running *thread* unless you have previously called the `detach()` method.  The `detach()` method just sets a flag that means, "trust me, I know what I'm doing, I don't need the handle anymore because I won't need to exert control over the running *thread* again."